# How to refresh DOM with newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I know this question was asked several times, but couldn't get the answer that works for me so here I am with my case.
I'm trying to make a jQuery plug-in that's add contact form to a certain page(It's not like there is no such a plug-ins but let's say I do this just for educational reasons). It is searching for `<div id="add_contacts"></div>` and creates the form in this div.
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_contacts').append('<div class="contact-from"></div>');
    $('<form></form>',{id:'new_contact'}).appendTo('.contact-form');
    $('<div>',{class:'contact_user_name'}).appendTo('#new_contact');

var name_field = $('<input>',{
    name:"contact_broker_fullname",
    id:"contact_user_name",
}).appendTo('.contact_user_name');

    var input_button = $('<input>',{
    name:"submit",
    type:"submit",
    value:"Send"
}).appendTo('#new_contact');

    var full_name=name_filed.val();//I'm not sure that this should be here at all.

    input_button.on('click',function(){
    ajax_send_contact(full_name);
    return false;
});
});
```

And here is the `ajax_send_contact(full_name)` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'../some.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{name:full_name},
    success: function (response){
        if (response) {
            $('#success').append('<span>All right.</span>');
        }
        else{
            $('#errors').append('<span>Something went wrong.</span>');
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#errors').append('<span>ERROR!</span>');
    }
});
```

I've read that when adding dynamically element to HTML they're not included into the DOM, so how can i operate with them. How i can get the value of the input so once the user click the Submit button the value is sent to ajax function. And I'm not asking only for this particular case but for the whole logic as I'm missing something quite important.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the typo in your first append:  `div class="contact-from"` should be `contact-form`.  Your assignment to full_name also contains a typo `filed` instead of `field`, but as you say you don't need this here.  Move your access of that field value into the ajax data object `name: $('#contact_user_name').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you read this but it's not true.
Adding elements to your page is DOM manipulation.
In fact there is a lot of DOM manipulation in your ready function.
DOM manipulations are costly, try to reduce them by grouping operations :

```
var formHtml = '';

formHtml += '<div class="contact-form">';
    formHtml += '<form id="new_contact">';
        formHtml += '<div class="contact_user_name">';
            formHtml += '<input type="text" name="contact_broker_fullname" id="contact_user_name">';
        formHtml += '</div>';
        formHtml += '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">';
    formHtml += '</form>';
formHtml += '</div>';

$('#add_contacts').append(formHtml); // Only 1 DOM manip.
```

There are errors in your code :

```
$('#add_contacts').append('<div class="contact-from"></div>');
...
var name_field = $('<input>',{
```

And then :

```
$('<form></form>',{id:'new_contact'}).appendTo('.contact-form');
...
var full_name=name_filed.val();
```

'contact-from' then 'contact-form'.
'name_field' then 'name_filed'.

In your code, you get the value of your input#contact_user_name right after you created the form,
that is to say before the user had any chance to input something in it.
You have to do this in your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, set the data with the value of the field right before firing the request:

```
data: { name: $('.contact_user_name input').val() }
```

And you can remove `var full_name=name_filed.val()`, it would only get the value the field had at the moment it was created, and apparently that variable wouldn't be in scope when you actually need it.

The rest of your code looks okay.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It worked. I guess i should spend more time on the logical flow of the code. Thanks